# Processing AWS ELB access logs (from S3 bucket to InfluxDB)

Tags: amazon-s3, influxdb, amazon-elb, access-log, telegraf

We would like to process AWS ELB access logs and write them into InfluxDB
to be used for application metrics and monitoring (ex. Grafana).

We configured ELB to store access logs into S3 bucket.

What would be the best way to process those logs and write them to InfluxDB?

What we tried so far was to mount S3 bucket to filesystem using s3fs and then use Telegraf agent for processing. But this approach has some issues: s3fs mounting looks like a hack, and all the files in the bucket are compressed and need to be unzipped before telegraf can process them which makes this task overcomplicated.

Is there any better way?

Thanks,
Oleksandr

Answer (score 0):

Can you just install the telegraf agent on the AWS instance that is generating the logs, and have them sent directly to InfluxDB in real-time?

Comment: Logs are generated by ELB and we don't have access to it